# EditText append is duplicating numbers on SDK 31

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher, android-textwatcher

NOTE: This seems to only be happening in Android 12 (SDK 31)

I have a pretty complex use case for a TextWatcher in which I need to change text as the user types, however I may need to change more than just the character they just typed.  For that reason I cannot use a InputFilter.

For this example to highlight the error I am seeing I have simplified my use case.  I would just like to add a space after every character typed.

In my TextWatcher:

```
override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
   editText.removeTextChangedListener(this)
   addSpace(s, start, before, count)
   editText.addTextChangedListener(this)
}

private fun addSpace(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
   val text = s ?: return
   val spaced = "$text  "
   editText.text.clear()
   editText.text.append(spaced)
}
```

Note: I am using clear() and append() to avoid the keyboard from switching.  If I use setText(), will switch back to the default keyboard.

This works just fine when adding letters:

[image]

However when adding numbers, it will duplicate each number.  Adding some logging, it seems onTextChanged is being called again after my changes are complete and I re-add the listener.

[image]

Again this works just fine on SDK 30, and SDK 32, so it seems Android fixed the regression, but does not yet have a patch for SDK 31.  Has anyone run into this?  Know if there is an existing ticket I can follow?  Having trouble finding any reference to this.

**UPDATE:**
Running into the same issue using *afterTextChanged(...)*

```
override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
   editText.removeTextChangedListener(this)
   addSpace(s)
   editText.addTextChangedListener(this)
}

private fun addSpace(s: Editable?) {
   val text = s ?: return
   val spaced = "$text  "
   s.clear()
   s.append(spaced)
}
```

Comment: This seems to happen on an API 31 emulator only with the on-screen keyboard and not a hardware keyboard.

Comment: @Cheticamp yes.  I also have a Pixel 4 in hand running API 31 which exhibits the same problem.  So its not happening only on the emulator.

Comment: OK. Not emulator specific, but is it a soft keyboard problem?

Comment: @Cheticamp, yes seems to be, pixel 4 is displaying a soft keyboard.  So yeah soft keyboard, and only on API 31, works on 30 and 32.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for[TextWatcher#onTextChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher#onTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int)):

> This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters beginning at start have just replaced old text that had length before. **It is an error to attempt to make changes to s from this callback.**

The emphasis is mine. `s: CharSequence?` and `editText.text` refer to the same structure, so your code is making prohibited changes with, it seems, unpredictable results.

Comment: Not sure that is the case, with plenty of folks solving similar problems w/ onTextChange.  Yet, worth a shot.  I tried using afterTextChanged, same issue.  Works on 30 and 32, bug on 31.

Comment: @lostintranslation I'd be curious to see your _afterTextChanged_ code that's not working.

Comment: Sure added, it's not much different.  Same result using editable to mod text or editText.setText(...).  Works on 30 and 32, bug on 31.

Comment: I think you have a case @lostintranslation. It seems random like a race condition. I am now curious if there will even be a fix for API 31.  Post a link to the bug report if you submit one.